# Maven Returning Error That References Class Which No Longer Exists In My Source Code

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a JAR using maven.

Maven is returning the below error when I try to build the JAR using the command: **mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e**. I have removed the full package names for each class in the error message.

**getSession() in ResourceHibernateDao cannot override getSession() in AbstractHibernateDao; overridden method is final
        public final Session getSession()**

AbstractHibernateDao no longer exists in my source code. I have moved all of its relevant code to a new class that ResourceHibernateDao inherits from. In the new class, the getSession() method is not final. Therefore, I am unsure why I am getting an error message and why AbstractHibernateDao is referenced when it no longer exists. I have tried deleting the target folder that maven builds to and deleting the artifact in my local repo, but maven keeps returning the same error. FYI, I am using maven version 2.2.1. Does anyone know why maven is referencing a nonexistent class and how to make it realize that the class no longer exists?

Comment: Add `-X` to the `mvn` command line, it will enable verbose debug output.

Comment: If `AbstractHibernateDao` doesn't exist then Maven shouldn't find it either, however from the error message it seems Maven thinks that `AbstractHibernateDao` is parent of `ResourceHibernateDao`. If that was the case before deletion, then Maven is referring to the old version of `ResourceHibernateDao`. Try deleting everything that's not required by Maven project. You can also try manually deleting artifacts related to your project in local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that I found an answer to my question. Turns out one of my imports had an incorrect package name.